# Sqlalchemy - group by after joinloaded

Tags: flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have a following model.

```
class Customer(db.Model):
id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('accounts.id'), primary_key=True)
firstname = db.Column(db.Unicode(128), index=True)
lastname = db.Column(db.Unicode(128), index=True)
account = db.relationship('Account',
                backref=db.backref('customer',
                            uselist=False,
                            cascade=DEFAULT_WITH_DELETE_CASCADE),
                single_parent=True,
                cascade=DEFAULT_WITH_DELETE_CASCADE,
                foreign_keys=[id])
```

I want to do eagarloading of accounts table when customer is loaded. There are some more filters and joins which I apply to the query and then want to group the results by Customer.id so I get unique results for customers.

```
query = Customer.query.join(Customer.account).options(joinedload(Customer.account))
query = query.order_by(Account.registered_on.desc()).group_by(Customer.id, Account.id)
```

But when I use group_by clause after joinloaded I get error. How can I use group_by after doing joinloaded?

```
ProgrammingError: (ProgrammingError) column "accounts_1.id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can group by a column in a a table that you joined with (using `joinedload`). From SQLAlchemy docs: `The joins produced by orm.joinedload() are anonymously aliased. The criteria by which the join proceeds cannot be modified, nor can the Query refer to these joins in any way, including ordering.` (http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/loading_relationships.html)

You would need to use a regular `join` function here and then `group_by`